# Breeze server side saving changes without Entity Framework

Tags: breeze

I am using breeze without Entity Framework, is there a way to save the whole change set in one go on the server side? Or do I have to loop through the list of entities and save each individual one based on the checking of the entity state? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: probably- what is your backing store?

Comment: Thanks for replying!! It is Relational database, Web API with micro orm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar scenario with NancyFx (Without EF - OrmLite as ORM), Breeze and AngularJs. I googled a lot but did not find any good resources which can help me.
After a lot of hit and trial coding, I wrote the code to accomplish.

Below are the brief steps.

1. Use EF only to generate metadata. You can remove EF in production.
2. Save EF Metadata into a metadata.js which will be used by client to load metadata.
3. Make changes in your application to pick metadata from js file and not from server.
4. Define your own SaveChanges method at server.

   ```
   private dynamic SaveChanges(dynamic arg)
   {
       var requestBody = this.Request.Body;
       int length = (int)requestBody.Length; //this is a dynamic variable.
       byte[] data = new byte[length];
       requestBody.Read(data, 0, length);

       JObject saveBundle = JObject.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data));

       for (int i = 0; i < saveBundle["entities"].Count(); i++)
       {
           JToken entity = saveBundle["entities"][i];

           switch ((string)entity["entityAspect"]["entityTypeName"])
           {
               case "Node:#Breeze":
                   Node node = NodeContext.Process(entity);
                   break;
           }
       }

       return this.Request.Body;
   }
   ```

"Node:#Breeze" should be replaced by "EntityName:NameSpace"
NodeContext should be replaced by some user defined class where we will be processing entity(CRUD operations) on base of entity state.

Comment: Thanks for replying! After a lot of research, I did the same implementation as your steps 1 - 3, for step 4 I used Breeze's SaveChange and implemented the underlying saving functions.

Comment: Well I think you already did what I got today. My reason for using "No Entity Framework" is because I need to deploy solution on Linux using Mono.
Earlier I rejected Breeze - NoDB Solution because "Breeze.ContextProvider" nuget package automatically downloads "Entity Framework Packages" so it look to me that NoDB solution uses EF assemblies too.

But Today, I just removed EF assemblies from project and hurray it is working and Now I dont have to write huge SaveChanges logic at server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly save the whole change set in a single EntityManager.saveChanges call. Take a look at the NoDb sample in the breeze.js.samples GitHub repo and you will see an example of this.

You will, of course, need to implement that actual save operation yourself on the server, but the server will receive the entire change set for you to work with.

In addition, if you don't want to use EF, there are several other breeze backend server technologies that you can use instead. Take a look at the breeze GitHub repos for .NET, Node, and Java versions of the .NET server.

- breeze.server.net
- breeze.server.node
- breeze.server.java

These include server implementations for the following combinations

- .NET/Entity Framework ( any SQL db that EF supports)
- .NET/Hibernate - ( any SQL db that NHibernate supports)
- Node/Sequelize -  ( MySql/Postgress databases)
- Node/Mongo     -  ( Mongo db databases)
- Java/Hibernate -  ( any SQL db that Hibernate supports)

Comment: Thanks Jay! The NoDb sample only works with one entity the TodoItem, and I can see it loops through the list sent from the client and saves each individual ones. I am able to send the whole change set (more than just one entity) to the server by using Breeze, so basically I have to loop through the entities, convert them to their model and save each by checking the entity state, there is not a handy function to save all?

Comment: The code to perform a save based on the saveBundle sent to the server is dependent on the capabilities of the backend.  EF is able to accept an entire change set and the Breeze EF server implementation makes use of this.  The NoDb sample shows an alternative implemention that just uses an in-memory store.  If your  ORM provides the capability to accept a change set then you can convert the saveBundle sent to the server into your ORM specific change set and submit it as a single operation.  Does this make sense?

Comment: It makes sense. The ORM is not capable to accept the change set. I try to avoid using EF as it is heavy and slow. Thanks Jay!